# reason: '-[__NSArrayI UTF8String]: terminate app when i am using Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Now i am using so much of object from different api and i want to save that object in to realm at the same time , i am hitter but it terminate the app with the error of

> -[__NSArrayI UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7fb2f00e70
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdaaafaad50'

so i need to known how it happens and what the reason Please any help me
about that and i need to known how to calculate the commitWriteTransaction time and when it finished to store.

Comment: The error message clearly says that somewhere you are calling `UTF8String` on an `NSArray` rather than on an expected `NSString`

Comment: yes @vadian thank you my mistake.... so sad.....

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: i am corrected @Florian Burel what my mistake result from the api was array thats what i did't check , my code below                                                        NSDictionary *reminderinfo= [jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"info"];
NSLog(@"reminderinfo: %@",reminderinfo);
NSString *reminder_code = [reminderinfo valueForKey:@"reminder_code"];                                     NSLog(@"reminder values: %@",reminder_code);

Comment: @HariNarayanan Can you please share complete code around crashes?